# Invalid rpc-bind-ip address when using a bash script to pass node IP to the --rpc-bind-ip argument

Tags: monerod

I need to install monero on 30 machines and I created a for script to do this.

```
for i in {1..10}

  monero --rpc-bind-ip 10.0.0.$i

done
```

The problem is that I keep getting a response of invalid IP during monero execution. Anyone know how to successfully pass the variable into `--rpc-bind-ip`?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually have 10 ethernet adapters?

Comment: Also, what are you actually trying to do? Because the script looks like it's trying to create 10 daemons on the same machine each running an RPC server on a different address.

Comment: I have 10 computers that I plan to use to run monero.

Comment: honestly, i am new to Monero. I am not sure what the --rpc-bind-ip do , any help is appreciated! thanks!

Comment: `--rpc-bind-ip` is used to bind the IP (as assigned to one of your ethernet cards) to be used for the RPC interface of the daemon. If you need to remotely access the daemon RPC, you would need to set this to the IP address of your ethernet card which can be accessed remotely or to 0.0.0.0 which means all ipv4 addresses on the machine.

Comment: "I have 10 computers that I plan to use to run monero" but for what purpose do you need it on 10 machines? The bash script in the question is attempting to run 10 instances on one machine (not 10 machines) and to each start RPC listening on different addresses (which I doubt you have 10 ethernet adapters on 1 machine).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your bash script is invalid:

1. you are missing `do` after the `for` line
2. `monero` should be `monerod`
3. you would also need the `--detach` option, as without it, `monerod` is running interactively.

Next, your script is actually trying to launch 10 instances of the daemon on a single machine. Not 10 machines each running monero. Also, these 10 instances are each trying to bind the RPC server to separate IP addresses on this same single machine, and I doubt very much you have 10 addresses assigned to your ethernet card(s) on this single machine.